# convert JSON array of key value pairs to JSON Array of strings in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

so i have a JSON Object `[{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"},{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"}]`

and i essentially need to remove the keys so the output looks like `[["val1","val2"],["val1","val2"]]` in Javascript.

short of iterating through the array and then iterating through all the properties and mapping to a new JSON object is there any way i can remove the keys from the object, and turn the values in to a list in an array?

please no string splicing/ regex.

Thanks.

Comment: Does the order of the array elements matter? Is it OK if it's `[["val2", "val1"], ["val1", "val2"]]`?

Comment: yes it does but the accepted answer by @BrunoLM does preserve order.

Comment: No it doesn't, since the objects themselves don't preserve order.

Comment: ahhh you are correct, thanks!@ i didn't notice it, b/c the first few arrays contained the same keyed data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using ES2015 (ES6)

```
const arr = [{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"},{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"}]
arr.map(o => Object.values(o));
```

See

- [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

Answer (score 0):

If you still need old browser support--pre ES6

```js
var arr = [{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"},{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"}];

arr = arr.map(function(o){
   var a = [];
   for(var i in o){
      a.push(o[i])
   }
   return a;
});
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Plain ES5 with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var array = [{ key1: "val1", key2: "val2" },{ key1: "val1", key2: "val2" }],
    mapped = array.map(function (o) {
        return Object.keys(o).map(function (k) {
            return o[k];
        });
    });

console.log(mapped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over the object and make new arrays.

```
for (var i = 0; i < yourobject.length; i++) {
    var myArray = [];
    for (var key in yourobject) {
         myArray.push(yourobject[key]
    }
    console.log(myArray)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
const arr = [{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"},{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"}];

const newArr = arr.map(obj => Object.values(obj));
```